# Sinon spy not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have two functions foo and bar in utilityService.js

```
export function foo() {
    return bar();
}

export function bar() {
    return 1;
}
```

In my test file i have imported utilityService.js and spied on bar function.
I expect callCount of spy to be 1 as foo is called but it is 0. Please suggest if I am missing anything.

```
import * as utilityService from '../services/utility-service';

let callSpy = sinon.spy(utilityService, 'bar');
expect(utilityService.foo()).to.equal(1);
expect(callSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Sinon documentation:](http://sinonjs.org/docs/)

> sinon.spy(object, "method") creates a spy for object.method and replaces the original method with the spy.

`import` creates an object called `utilityService` which references `foo` and `bar`. `Sinon` replaces `utilityService.bar()` with its own function. But `foo` doesn't call `utilityService.bar()`, but `bar()` **directly**. So the call doesn't go through `Sinon`'s replaced function.

I hope it's clear.